# Reading single row in PyShp with shapefile.Reader

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I use PyShp and `shapefile.Reader` to read shapefile files.

If I want to read a whole file I use:

```
with shapefile.Reader(file) as shp:
    for row_num, row in enumerate(shp.iterRecords()):
        print(row)
```

But I would like to read a single row from shapefile file with `shapefile.Reader`, for example row number 100. I read documentation and I didn't find any solution. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`shapefile.Reader` loads all data to the memory. After using `shapefile.Reader("file_path")` you can get a specific row by index using `shapeRecords` method which returns a list containing all rows, then, you can get the specific row.

````
```
import shapefile

with shapefile.Reader(file) as shp:
    row = shp.shapeRecords()[99] # row with index 99 (100th row)
```
````